# Finding the whole line of text based on a pattern. (Regex)

Tags: java, regex

I'm pretty new to RegEx and would like to get enlisted on this problem.

Here is an example:

```
String string = "John gets a Star Wars ticket" + \n
                "Keith gets a soccer ticket" + \n
                "Mary gets a Star Wars ticket"
```

What is the regular expression so that the output will look like this for lines that have the   `Star Wars` in it:

```
John gets a Star Wars ticket
Mary gets a Star Wars ticket
```

Thanks.

Comment: What have you....tried?

Comment: This more like a work order than a request to help with an attempt that doesn't work. Please show what you've tried.

Comment: Oh I forgot to add. I think I could shorten it by using just the word `Star`. The Regex I tried was `^.*Star.*$`, somehow it didn't return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    String string = "John gets a Star Wars ticket\n" +
            "Keith gets a soccer ticket\n" +
            "Mary gets a Star Wars ticket";
    for (String line : string.split("\n")) {
        if (line.matches(".*Star Wars.*")) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful to me. I found where i made the mistake already.